# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function computed at $x=-2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be defined by sending $x$ to $1$ if $x \geq 0$ and to $0$ otherwise. Compute $Mf(-2)$.

This is the first time I've seen computation questions involving the Hardy-Littlewood function, so I'm not exactly sure what to do. By definition of $Mf$, let $I$ be intervals (since we're in $\mathbb{R}$) centred at $x = -2$, then $$Mf(-2) = \sup \frac{1}{|I|}\int_I |f(y)|dy.$$

I'm thinking of choosing a particular interval, say, $I=[-5,1]$, and trying it out. So $|I| = 6$, we have $$\frac{1}{6}\int _I |f(y)|dy = \frac{1}{6}\left(\int_{[-5,0)}|f(y)|dy + \int_{[0,1]}|f(y)|dy\right).$$
The first term in the bracket is $0$, whereas the second term becomes the integral of $1$ in $[0,1]$ which is just $1$, hence we evaluate the whole term to be $\frac{1}{6}$. If I now try the interval $[-6,2]$, I will obtain $\frac{1}{8}(0+2) = \frac{1}{4}$, which is bigger than $\frac{1}{6}$. If I now try $[-104,100]$, it will be $\frac{1}{204}(0+100)$ which is $\frac{25}{51}$.

It seems to me like we're getting closer and closer to $\frac{1}{2}$ which could most likely be the supremum. So I thought of letting $I$ be the arbitrary interval $[-2-n,-2+n]$ and then we evaluate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2n}\left(0 + \int_{[0,n-2]}|f(y)|dy\right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2n}(n-2)= \frac{1}{2}.$$
Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: It is correct if you are writing $n$ for a  positive real variable. You cannot maximize over just  interger values of $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy good point, I actually used an integer to understand the question better but then forgot $n$ should be an arbitrary positive real number.